# trigger split on dash

Tags: mysql, triggers

trying to create a trigger that will split the filename of a document using the dash and then insert those 2 entries into 2 separate fields

ie.  filename could be 12345-67890 and i need 12345 to go in to 1 field and 67890 in to another field - the entries dont have any specific length so it could always be different but i have this as an idea but it isnt working

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER triggername
    BEFORE INSERT ON triggername.tablename
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    /* Move the value from one column to another */
    SET NEW.DOCID = NEW.DOCID;
    /* Check a text field with IF statement */

    SPLIT_STR(filename, '-', 1) as ponum,
    SPLIT_STR(filename, '-', 2) as invoicenum
    END IF;
    END;
    //
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that I recommend is to use [common_schema](http://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) and specifically functions [`get_num_tokens()`](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/get_num_tokens.html) and [`split_token()`](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/split_token.html), this will help.

Here a simple example of the use that you can adapt for your solution:

```sql
...
SET `_filename` := NEW.`filename`, `_delimiter` := '-';
IF (`common_schema`.`get_num_tokens`(`_filename`, `_delimiter`) = 2) THEN
    SET `ponum` := `common_schema`.`split_token`(`_filename`, `_delimiter`, 1);
    SET `invoicenum` := `common_schema`.`split_token`(`_filename`, `_delimiter`, 2);
END IF;
...
```